# ocaml implementation of pipe

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to implement something like a `pipe` function.

**Input:** a list of functions

**Output:** a function

**Example:**

```
# pipe [(fun y -> y+5);(fun y -> y*3)] 1 = 18
# pipe [(fun z -> z*3);(fun z -> z+5)] 1 = 8
```

**My problem:**

A helper function `composite` takes two arguments, which are a function `f` and a list of function `l`. If the list is empty, it returns the function `f`.
If it is not, `f` will be an argument of the head of list `g`. 
However, I got a syntax error. I don't figure out what's going on.
Has anyone found an error?

```
let pipe l =
  let composite f l = match l with
      []->f
    | g::gs -> (fun h -> (g -> f)) in
  List.fold_left composite (fun x -> x) l
```

Answer (score 3):

`(fun h -> (g -> f))` is not syntactically correct, and I'm not sure what it is supposed to mean.

The pattern-matching of your `composite` function looks like what you would write for a recursive function, but then you're trying to define it non-recursively for use with `fold_left`. Either way would be good, but you need to make up your mind, because here you've a sad compromise that does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. as you can see, "g" is the first element of the list, which is a function. For the second pattern matching, if "l" is a list that has at least one element, I want to get a function "g(f(x))". How do I represent this idea?

Comment: If `f` and `g` are values of type `'a -> 'a`, the function "g(f(x))" is `fun x -> g (f x)`.